# SQL error for adding a table

Tags: mysql

I get this error but I dont know what im doing wrong? Im just filling in this typical Table. (I am new at SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE Post (id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, datum timestamp(3) NOT NULL, tekst varchar(255) NOT NULL, eigenaar varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id, eigenaar));
```

This is the error I get : 
[image: error]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try putting backticks around the column names.

Comment: hi, thanks already for the answer. But that doesnt work. greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a mysql version 5.6.3 or earlier, that does not support the [store of fractional temporal values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in fields, hence you get the error message a `(3)` right after the timestamp definition. Remove the fractional part or upgrade your mysql version to at least 5.6.4.